# Ajax request stays on readyState=1

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

As the title says, im trying to use ajax with this HTML and recieve the chosen vehicle on the select list in the php file to insert it on database. After this, if the insertion is correct the php is suppose to send back the id(autoincrement) associated with the new insertion and show it on the HTML. The problem is that the ajax connection stops at readyState=1 ( just after opening the communication) and no error is shown in console log.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<select name="type" id="type">
    <option value="Coche">Car</option>
    <option value="Motocicleta">Cicle</option>
    <option value="Barco">Ship</option>
</select>

    <button id="btn_search">Search</button>

    <div class="List" id="List">

    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var xhreq=new XMLHttpRequest();
    var btn_search=document.getElementById("btn_search");
    var type=document.getElementById("type");
    btn_search.addEventListener("click",find_veh);

    function find_veh(event){
        console.log("Find_veh1-> onreadystate:"+xhreq.readyState);
        xhreq.open("GET","Ej1.php?q="+type.value,true);
        console.log("Find_veh2-> onreadystate:"+ xhreq.readyState);
        xhreq.onreadystatechange= show_veh;
        xhreq.send(null);
        console.log("Find_veh3-> onreadystate:"+ xhreq.readyState);
    }


    function show_veh(){
        if((xhreq.readyState==4) && (xhreq.status==200)){
            console.log("Show_veh correct")
            document.getElementById("show_vehi").innerText=xhreq.responseText;
        }else {
            console.log("Error in show_veh");
        }
    }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

PHP

```
     <?php
    $dbConn = new mysqli("192.168.1.62", "root", "pass", "AJAX");

if ($dbConn->connect_error) {
} else {
    if (isset($_GET["q"])) {
        $q = $_GET["q"];

        $query = 'SELECT id FROM Vehiculos WHERE tipo='.$q.";";
        $result = $dbConn->query($query);
        $listHTML .= "<ul>";
        while($idVehi = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            $listHTML .="<li>".$idVehi["id"]."</li>";
        }
        $listHTML .="</ul>";

      echo $listHTML;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code above appears to lack the HTML element with ID `show_vehi` which is used by the ajax callback to display the result. With than said the manner in which you open the XMLHttpRequest object and then perform the actual request seems peculiar - I'd normally expect the XMLHttpRequest to be opened as and when the request is to be made rather than at pageload.

In essence there doesn't appear to be anything intrinsically wrong with your ajax ~ it works so perhaps it is a misunderstanding of the various stages of the XHR request that has given cause for concern regarding the `readyState` staying at 1.

The following has some slight modifications to your original javascript to indicate information that you might not have noticed ( the callback error is not really an error ) and, because the test page was called `ej1.php` the ajax request here is processed on the same page by sending some random text as reply rather than the actual db query.

```
<?php

    if( !empty( $_GET['q'] ) ){
        exit('Some sort of response for the ajax callback to process...'.date(DATE_ATOM));
    }

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select name="type" id="type">
            <option value="Coche">Car</option>
            <option value="Motocicleta">Cicle</option>
            <option value="Barco">Ship</option>
        </select>
        <button id="btn_search">Search</button>
        <button id="btn_search_alternative">Search (Alternative)</button>
        <div class="List" id="List"></div>
        <div id='show_vehi'></div>

        <script>
            var css={
                red:'color:red',
                green:'color:green',
                blue:'color:blue'
            }



            function ajax( url, type, callback ){
                var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
                        if( this.status==200 && this.readyState==4 ){
                            console.info( '%cAfter Response: %s', css.green, xhr.readyState );
                            callback( this.response );
                        }
                    };
                    console.info( '%cBefore Open: %s', css.red, xhr.readyState );
                    xhr.open('GET', url+'?q='+type,true );
                    console.info( '%cBefore Send: %s', css.blue, xhr.readyState );
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                    xhr.send( null );
            }

            document.getElementById('btn_search_alternative').addEventListener('click',function(e){
                function callback(r){
                    document.getElementById('show_vehi').textContent=r;
                }
                ajax( 'ej1.php', document.getElementById('type').value, callback );
            });





            /* slightly modified original */
            var xhreq=new XMLHttpRequest();
            console.info('After Initialisation: %d',xhreq.readyState)


            var btn_search=document.getElementById("btn_search");
            var type=document.getElementById("type");
            btn_search.addEventListener("click",find_veh);



            function find_veh(event){
                console.log("Before Open: Find_veh1-> onreadystate:"+xhreq.readyState);
                xhreq.open("GET","Ej1.php?q="+type.value,true);
                console.log("After Open, Before Change: Find_veh2-> onreadystate:"+ xhreq.readyState);
                xhreq.onreadystatechange= show_veh;
                xhreq.send(null);
                console.log("After Send: Find_veh3-> onreadystate:"+ xhreq.readyState);
            }


            function show_veh(){
                if((xhreq.readyState==4) && (xhreq.status==200)){
                    console.log("Response received: Show_veh correct")
                    document.getElementById("show_vehi").innerText=xhreq.responseText;
                }else {
                    console.log("Error in show_veh: readyState=%d status=%d",xhreq.readyState,xhreq.status);
                }
            }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

However - the real problem lies in your PHP code. The SQL statement is completely vulnerable to SQL injection so I'd suggest learning how to implement `Prepared Statements` - I appreciate that currently this is not live due to the class C IP address for database host but now is the time to make the changes.

You could try something like this (untested)

```
<?php

    if( !empty( $_GET['q'] ) ){

        $html=array();


        $dbConn = new mysqli("192.168.1.62", "root", "pass", "AJAX");
        $sql='select `id` from `vehiculos` where tipo=?';
        $stmt=$dbConn->prepare( $sql );

        $q=filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'q', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );

        if( $stmt ){
            $stmt->bind_param('s', $q );
            $res=$stmt->execute();

            if( $res ){
                $stmt->store_result();
                $stmt->bind_result( $id );
                $html[]='<ul>';
                while( $stmt->fetch() )$html[]=sprintf( '<li>%s</li>',$id );
                $html[]='</ul>';
            }
        }

        exit( implode( PHP_EOL, $html ) );
    }
?>
```

Comment: I made the changes you suggested and fixed the show_vehi problem, although it didnt fix the problem. I tried to adjust and use your code and it didnt work neither so i tried to restart PhpStorm few times and now both codes are perfectly fine. I dont know what the problem was/is, but may be related to the program itself. Anyway,thanks for the answer.